# Haskell Sqlite3 - Catching exceptions

Tags: sqlite, exception, haskell, catch-block

I would like to know how I can catch an exception if raised by the following piece of code

```hs
query_3 <- quickQuery' conn_1 "SELECT MAX(high) \
                              FROM historicalData " []                                    
mapM_ (putStrLn . convertSqlValToString) query_3
```

I got to know that it's possible with something called "catchSql" , but have no idea how to use it in the above code

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it now, but try something like:

```hs
handleSql print $ do
    query_3 <- quickQuery' conn_1 "SELECT MAX(high) FROM historicalData" []
    mapM_ (putStrLn . convertSqlValToString) query_3
```

It uses

```hs
handleSql :: (SqlError -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
```

(which is just `catchSql :: IO a -> (SqlError -> IO a) -> IO a` with its arguments reversed).

Function `handleSql` runs the action given as its second argument, in your case `quickQuery'` followed by `mapM_`. And if a `SqlError` occurs during that part, it passes it to the function given as the first argument. So in the above example, if a `SqlError` occurs during the inner block, `handleSql` will call `print` on it..